# Google Sheet Array Formula Put blank

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, lambda, sum, google-sheets-formula

I have this formula

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(C$3:F$3), H4:L4+C4:F4/$C$1, ""))
```

[image]

How i can modify this array formula to return Blank like in I7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=BYROW(B34:F38, LAMBDA(x, INDEX(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, x), " "),,1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Still not working, i modified, the final output I'm trying to get https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FMBkmMKJuIn0qtxDzvaWG2x5IpcR92X4-G9b8DUd9Z4/edit#gid=0